# Can't launch email via intent when downloading apk from web site

Tags: android, email, android-intent

i want to launch an email application via an intent in my pogram. 
When i run my program from Android Studio with the phone connected via USB, all works fine. Now i generate the apk of my application and i try to download it from a website in order to install it on my phone. When i click on the button to launch the email application, the phone tells me that "all apps associated with this action have been disabled blocked or are not installed".
Does anyone knows why my application works when installed from USB and doesn't work when installed from a web site ?
Thanks a lot.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/plain"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, tab_email);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sauvegarde BD Mon Coffre");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Pick an Email provider"),12);
```

Comment: check your manifest file change the package name I hope it will work

Comment: one more solution convert apk as URL online and than sent that URL link

Comment: What do ypu mean by changing the package name, what name should i put ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why but by adding the following line in my code :

```
emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

now when i download my apk from a website, all works fine, i've got a chooser that appears to select an email client when i click on the button to launch the email application.